# regular expression for getting numbers in between

Tags: regex, go

So I have something like this:

string . (numbers1 ,numbers2 ,numbers3)
so something like this:

bla bla bla . (1234 , 5678 , 012)

I would like to get the first numbers, i.e. the numbers between ( and , & disregarding the space before the comma at the same time in one regex, then get the second number in another regex without getting the first so between the first ' and the second '

I've tried to do the following to get the first one but that didn't work even with the space:

```
^\(\d*,$
```

I even tried this:

```
^.*?\([^\d]*(\d+)[^\d]*\).*$
```

And this:

```
\[\((\d+)\).*?\]
```

I'm testing it in here: https://regex101.com/ and I keep getting no match for some reason

I'm trying to implement it using the Go language

Comment: it's easy with programming language

Comment: [`(?:\(|\G *, *)\K(\d+)(?=[ ,\d]*\))`](https://regex101.com/r/HNW0Gf/2)?

Comment: So, how many groups of numbers do you want to get, 2 ? (`1234` , `5678` , 012)

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/aZQrIr/1

Comment: [First](https://regex101.com/r/lTYnc0/2) and [second](https://regex101.com/r/lTYnc0/3)

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew. If u added this as an answer, I'll choose it as the correct one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [first regex](https://regex101.com/r/lTYnc0/2) is

```
\(\s*(\d+)
```

**Details**

- `\(` - a `(`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits

And the [second one](https://regex101.com/r/lTYnc0/3) is

```
\(\s*\d+\s*,\s*(\d+)
```

Same as above (with the removed capturing group around the first digit matching pattern), but `\s*,\s*(\d+)` is added:

- `\s*,\s*` - a `,` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits

[Go playground demo](https://play.golang.org/p/KMWjI4sFw6):

package main

```
import (
    "regexp"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var str = `bla bla bla . (1234 , 5678 , 012)`
    var re = regexp.MustCompile(`\(\s*(\d+)`)

    match := re.FindStringSubmatch(str)
    fmt.Println(match[1])

    var re2 = regexp.MustCompile(`\(\s*\d+\s*,\s*(\d+)`)
    match2 := re2.FindStringSubmatch(str)
    fmt.Println(match2[1])
}
```

Results:

```
1234
5678
```

Comment: Sure. You got it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get all that you want with a single regexp and named groups:

for example with python `re` module:

```
import re

CUSTOM_REGEXP = r".+\.\s{0,}\((?P<first>\d+)\s{0,},\s{0,}(?P<second>\d+)\s{0,},\s{0,}(?P<third>\d+)\)"
match = re.match(CUSTOM_REGEXP, "bla bla bla.(1234 , 5678 , 012)"
m.group("first")  # 1234
m.group("second") # 5678
m.group("third")  # 012
```

by parts:

`.+` any character at least one repetition

`\.` literal dot

`\s{0,}` optional space

`\(` literal parenthesis

`(?P<first>\d+)` named group of at least one integer

`,` literal comma

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not specify a programming language or how you want your output it's hard to give a specific answer but here are some regular expressions that I think could be what you're after.

- Get all the numbers in one expression using groups: [(\s?(\d+)\s?,\s?(\d+)\s?,\s?(\d+)\s?)](https://regex101.com/r/bQ7hH0/1)
- Pull out first number (in group 1): [(\s*(\d+)\s*,.*)](https://regex101.com/r/lL0ETY/1)
- Pull out second number (in group 1): [(.*?,\s*(\d+)\s*,.*)](https://regex101.com/r/IAJhgn/1)
- Pull out third number (in group 1): [(.*,.*,\s*(\d+)\s*)](https://regex101.com/r/EBM57p/1)

If any of these are what you were looking for it's up to you to implement them without knowing your desired language.

Comment: (\s*(\d+)\s*,.*) this is the only thing that worked.  and it retrieved the 1st group correctly. Why does the language matter?